# Possible to enable title bar on tables but not on phones?

Tags: android

I have an app that I am trying to make more tablet compatible. In the phone version I have the theme set to no title bar which I thinks looks the best on the phones. Only problem is in Android 3.0 the menu buttons are moved to the title bar(action bar). I was wondering if it is possible to have it have a title bar on the tablet but still have it be no title bar on the phones. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method for detecting a tablet in the [Google I/O app source](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/UIUtils.java) which looks like this:

```
public class UIUtils {

    public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
        // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
        // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }

    public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
        // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
        // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
        return isHoneycomb() && (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }
}
```

In your Activity you can simply call

```
if (!UIUtils.isHoneycombTablet(this)) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```